# Privileges for spark sql with sentry

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, privilege, apache-sentry

I'm trying to make the privileges to access Spark-SQL with sentry, and spark sql connects with thrift port withe hiveserver2( --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port). However, while I can limit users' privileges on hive successfully, I cannot limit the access with spark SQL through sentry.

Anyone who met with the same problem?

Comment: According to [this posting](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/Spark-and-Sentry/td-p/41273) by a Cloudera employee, Spark SQL does not currently go via HiveServer2

Answer (score 2):

1. Follow [the doc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables)，config hive in Spark.
2. Add Sentry jars to the classpath, Spark will load them automatically.

It works for me.